# MongoDB C# Driver -> Check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to implement quite easy algorithm.
Let's say that we have some simple hierarchy:
(root) A => B => C
Every nove represent some ID and every ID contain many record.

Record have:
 (string) Id and (List)ExcludedId

So we can have:

rec1:{ Id: A; ExcludedId = [B]}

rec2:{ Id: A; ExcludedId = [D]}

rec3:{ Id: A; ExcludedId = [B]}

rec1':{ Id: A; ExcludedId = []}

rec1":{ Id: C; ExcludedId = []}

rec2':{ Id: D; ExcludedId = []}

Now algorithm looks like:

If I want to take records from C I need to take:
C,B,A exist in Id AND
C,B,A NOT exists in ExcludedId

So I wrote:

```
public List<Record> GetRecords(string id, List<string> parentId)
{
    if (parentsIds == null)
            parentsIds = new List<string>();

    var collection = _mongoDbConnection.GetCollection<Records>();

    var allScenarios = parentsIds.ToList();
    allScenarios.Add(Id);

    var myfilter = Builders<Record>.Filter.And(
            Builders<Record>.Filter.Where(record => allScenarios.Any(s => record.Id.Contains(s))),
            Builders<Record>.Filter.Not(Builders<Record>.Filter.Where(record => allScenarios.Any(s => record.ExcludedIds.Contains(s))))
        );

return collection.Find(myfilter).ToList();
}
```

But I receive an exception which says:

```
Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]).Where({document}{Id}.Contains({document}))).'
```

Can you help me with that? Thank you in advance

Edit:

Changed:

```
Builders<Record>.Filter.Where(record => allScenarios.Any(s => record.Id.Contains(s))
```

to

```
Builders<Record>.Filter.In(ts => ts.ScenarioGuid, parentScenarioGuids),
```

And that works! But I have problem with

```
Builders<Record>.Filter.Not(Builders<Record>.Filter.Where(record => allScenarios.Any(s => record.ExcludedIds.Contains(s))))
        );
```

Because ExcludedIds is List. As a result:

```
Builders<Record>.Filter.Nin(ts => ts.ExcludedScenarioGuids, allScenarios)
```

says

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type FieldDefinition<Records, string> because it not a delegate type.
```

Exception is pointed to ts => ts.ExcludedScenarioGuids

Edit2:

Such as @cloudikka wrote, the solution is AnyNin and In. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `In` method instead of `Where` method. Alternatively, `Nin` method. Both can be used for a single value fields. Also there are `AnyIn` and opposite `AnyNin` for an array fields.

Related source:

[In method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_In__1_1.htm)

[Nin method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Nin__1_1.htm)

[AnyIn method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyIn.htm)

[AnyNin method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyNin.htm)

Comment: Thanks! Partially solved my issues. But still have problem with Nin such I wrote in my question(I edited post). Can you help again?

Comment: I bet it is Array field and in that case you have to use [AnyNin method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyNin__1.htm)

Comment: Thank you! I found anyNin a couple minutes ago. But basically - your answer helped me.

Comment: I am going to update answer with AnyIn and AnyNin! Pleasure to help. Happy coding!